# Whonix Linux Installer bash script signature verification failure

Tags: gnupg

I am verifying the **Whonix Linux Installer bash script**.
I imported the GPG key first following the instructions from the [wiki](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main/Project_Signing_Key#Debian_and_Derivatives) using the Debian procedure.
I could successfully verify the Virtualbox image.
Although when verifying the `dist-installer-cli` from [here](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Linux) using **option B** with

```
gpg --verify-options show-notations --verify dist-installer-cli.asc dist-installer-cli
```

I get a `BAD Signature`:

```
gpg: Signatur vom Do 11 Jän 2024 11:57:15 CET
gpg:                mittels RSA-Schlüssel 6E979B28A6F37C43BE30AFA1CB8D50BB77BB3C48
gpg: FALSCHE Signatur von "Patrick Schleizer <adrelanos@kicksecure.com>" [unbekannt]
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to verify the installer script with signify:
`signify-openbsd -C -p derivative.pub -x dist-installer-cli.sig dist-installer-cli`

Again, I get a bad signature:
`signify-openbsd: signature verification failed`